# (Sub)-categories affix stacked sidebar in Bootstrap

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement a navbar affix in Symfony2 with Bootstrap, but I have not managed to find any useful resources so far.
What I would like to do is having some Categories and SubCategories and when the user clicks on a Category, then the available SubCategories are popping up.

Initial state example:

```
+Category 1
+Category 2
+Category 3
+Category 4
```

After clicking on Category 1 link example:

```
+Category 1
 -SubCategory 1
 -SubCategory 2
 -SubCategory 3
+Category 2
+Category 3
+Category 4
```

What I have so far is:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <div id="affix-nav" class="affix sidebar col-sm-3">
                <ul class="nav sidenav" data-spy="affix">
                    {% for cat in categories %}
                        {% include 'ToolBundle:Default:sidebar_bit.html.twig' %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

...and that is ***sidebar_bit.html.twig***

```
<li>
    <a href="#cat_{{ cat.getId }}">{{ cat.getDefaultName }}</a>
    {% if no_subs is not defined %}
        <ul class="nav">
            {% for cat in cat.getChildren %}
                {% include 'ToolBundle:Default:sidebar_bit.html.twig' with {'no_subs': true} %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

Thanks alot in advance and do not hesitate for additional info if is required.

**UPDATE**

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0uwegh6k/2/

Comment: Maybe update your question with some of the rendered html.  If you have not already then I'd suggest making a pure bootstrap test page just to ensure you have all the bootstrap attributes and structure correct.

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle example is messed up, but it looks like you have to add some js to make it work or you can use the boostrap 3 toggle link is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

How it works is like `data-toggle="collapse"` on the trigger and target it using `href="collapseExample"` or `data-target="#collapseExample"` as shown in the link above

```
 <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" >Europe</a>
            <ul class="nav" id="collapseExample">
                <li>
                    <a href="#cat_13">England</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#cat_14">Spain</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

  <ul>
```